# linux execve, segmentation fault (strcmp_sse42)

Tags: c, linux, gdb, strcmp, execve

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(){
   int x,y,status, i;
   int cnt = 0;
   int flag = 0;
   char buf[50];
   char str[50];
   char * argv[10];
   char * ptr;


   for(i=0; i<10; i++){
    printf("$");
    gets(buf);
    strcpy(str, buf);

    ptr = strtok(buf, " ");

    while(ptr != NULL){
      argv[cnt] = ptr;
      cnt++;
      ptr = strtok(NULL," ");
    }



    if(!strcmp(argv[cnt-1], "&")) {
      argv[cnt-1] = 0;
      flag = 1;
    }
    else {
        argv[cnt] = 0;
    }



    if(!strcmp(argv[cnt-1], "exit")) exit(0); 

    x=fork();

    if (x==0){
        sleep(1);
        printf("I am child to execute %s\n", str);
        y=execve(argv[0], argv, 0);

        if (y<0){
           perror("exec failed");
           exit(1);
        }

    }
    else {
      if(flag == 0) { 
          wait(&status); 
      }
    }


    flag = 0;
    cnt = 0;
   }
}
```

run this code in linux then, 
segement falut (core dump)

also when using gdb,

==========================================================

Program received signal SIGSEGV, 
Segmentation fault.
0x0000003b6572fa96 in __strcmp_sse42 () 
from /lib64/libc.so.6

==========================================================

why it is not working?

if I type
/bin/ls -al (anything without '&')
good working

buf type
/bin/ls -al &
error

Comment: OT: Do not use `gets(buf)`! Use `fgets(buf, 50, stdin)` instead.

Comment: regardless of what visual studio will allow, the only valid return type from `main()` is `int`, not `void`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enter an `&`, the variable `argv[cnt-1]` will be set to NULL, therefore in `if(!strcmp(argv[cnt-1], "exit"))` the first argument of the function `strcmp` will be NULL, which will crash the application...

Furthermore your code does not check any buffer overflow, index out of bound, ... This code is quite "dangerous"

This implies, that:

- you should not use `gets`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1694042/808101
- Check that `argv` (note: this variable name is maybe not a good one, argv is very often the arguments of the program itself) array is big enough when inserting element in it

Comment: @JongSeokKim I improved my answer, if my answer did resolve your problem, please validate it.